# Обоснование алгоритма НОК

Tags: алгоритм

Вообщем нарыл вот такой алгоритм нахождения НОК 2 чисел. Кто-нибудь объясните, пожалуйста, как он работает + желательно блок-схему.

(На входе числа `a`, `b`)

```
xa = a
xb = b
While a <> b
  If a > b Then
    a = a-b 
  ElseIf a < b Then
    b = b-a
  EndIf
Endwhile

n = (xa * xb) / a
```

(На выходе `n`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В цикле находится НОД, а через него и НОК (в последней формуле).
НОД находится по алгоритму Евклида. Если a и b оба делятся на d, то их разность a - b тоже делится на d. При a > b число a - b меньше a. В противном случае можно из b вычесть a. Итак, для каждой пары (a, b) при  a<> b можно найти пару меньших чисел, у которых тот же наибольший общий делитель. Процесс прекращается тогда, когда a = b. Это и есть НОД.

Comment: А вот есть похожий алгоритм, но без умножения/деления. Можете по нему дать какие=нибудь комментарии?
TextWindow.Title = "Нахождение наименьшего общего кратного"
TextWindow.WriteLine("Введите а: ")
a = TextWindow.ReadNumber()
xa = a
TextWindow.WriteLine("Введите b: ")
b = TextWindow.ReadNumber()
xb = b
While a <> b
  If a < b Then
    a = a+xa 
  ElseIf a > b Then
    b = b+xb
  EndIf
Endwhile
TextWindow.WriteLine("НОК: " + a)